# image picker appears momentarily on IPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
        picker.delegate = self; 

        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        popover.delegate = self;
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame
                                 inView:self.view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                               animated:YES];
        [picker release];
```

It should place an image picker dialog on screen in IPad. It works OK on simulator, but on device the picker appears momentarily and disappears.

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
picker.delegate = self; 
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
self.popoverController = popover;          
popoverController.delegate = self;
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                               animated:YES];
[picker release];
```